# Writing steps in rspec-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, automated-tests, rspec-rails

I'm just getting into testing and I'm wondering how to write steps for RSpec specs, so I can reuse a lot of functions such as logging in, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Usually tests should be in isolation from one another; if a lot of your tests need to do the same thing, that suggests that they're duplicating some work. But sometimes that's unavoidable -- you'll frequently need to have a logged-in user handy to test authenticated things, for example.

Especially in the case of Ruby testing, chances are very good that someone has already written a library to solve the specific problem you want. For example, it's very common to need some data existing before an operation can be tested properly -- and that is why **[factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)** exists.

If you want to do behavior-driven integration testing that walks through all the steps a user would actually do, you should use [**Cucumber**](http://cukes.info/) instead.

If you want to reuse methods across different places, you can put shared code in `spec/support`:

```
# spec/support/consumable_helper.rb
module ConsumableHelper
  def consume(consumable)
    calories = consumable.om_nom_nom
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ConsumableHelper
end
```

If you want to test the same behavior in multiple areas, use `shared_examples_for` and `it_behaves_like`:

```
shared_examples_for "a Consumable" do
  it "should be delicious" do
    subject.should be_delicious
  end

  it "should provide nutrition" do
    subject.calories.should > 0
  end
end

describe Fruit do
  it_behaves_like "a Consumable"
end

describe Meat do
  it_behaves_like "a Consumable"
end
```

Comment: Irrelevant side-note. I prefer to use an indefinite article... `shared_examples_for "a Consumable"` and `it_behaves_like "a Consumable"`.  I just find the DSL reads better :)